# Representing Qubit Operator in Circuit

Tags: qiskit, programming, circuit-construction

I am trying to represent a quantum circuit schematically with some operators in QISKIT. I know I can create some operator with `Operator()` in quantum_info from a circuit circ like

```
Q1=quantum_info.Operator(circ)
```

To add the $Q_1$ operator to the circuit I can do

```
circ.append(Q1, [0, 1])
```

which adds $Q_1$ operator to the circuit and maps the 0th bit of the circuit to the 0th bit of the $Q_1$ operator and 1st bit of the circuit to the 1st bit of the $Q_1$ operator.  The resulting circuit for a 4-qubit circuit circ is

[image]

I was wondering how to edit the label of the operator. Right now it's just showing Unitary in the circuit block. I tried to find this in the QISKIT documentation. So far, no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that is to use [`QuantumCircuit.unitary`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.unitary.html) method as follows

```
circ.unitary(Q1, [0, 1], 'Custom Label')
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. So it seems the operator method does not have similar flexibility then, we need to resort to the Unitary method.